# Getting java.lang.VerifyError while sending mail using javax.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, verifyerror

I am trying to send a mail with attachment using javax.mail functionality, below is my code:

```
// create the message part
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
// fill message
messageBodyPart.setText(strmessage);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
AdcsipLogger.adcsipLog("begin exportFile...........");
ExportFile exportFile = buildQuestionnaireReport(questionnaire);
// Part two is attachment
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new ExportFileDataSource(exportFile);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(questionnaire.getName() + ".pdf");
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
// Put parts in message
message.setContent(multipart);
// Send the message
Transport.send(message);
```

I am getting an exception at line:
**messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));**

Below is the extract from stacktrace:

```
[10/30/13 14:44:38:089 CET] 00000062 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet QuestionnaireControl in application A430-CADCSIP-V8.0_Run4. Exception created : java.lang.VerifyError: javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)V
```

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're running in WebSphere, right?

Do you have the JavaMail jar file included in your application?  If so, it may be conflicting with the version included in WebSphere.